# Elasticsearch query and aggregation on indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have multiple elasticsearch indices and I would like to get the `doc_count` of how many documents matched the query for each index (even if no documents matched for an index). I tried this (using elasticsearch.js):

```
{
  index: 'one,or,many,indices,here',
  query: {
    query_string: {
      query: 'hello',
    },
  },
  aggs: {
    group_by_index: {
      terms: {
        field: '_index',
        min_doc_count: 0,
      },
    },
  },
  from: 0,
  size: 20,
};
```

This only works if I specify all indices on the `index` key. However, I don't always want to match documents across all indices in my search hits.

So I came up with:

```
{
  index: 'all,indices,here',
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          query_string: {
            query: 'hello',
          },
        },
        {
          terms: {
            _index: 'only,search,hits,indices,here',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  aggs: {
    group_by_index: {
      terms: {
        field: '_index',
        min_doc_count: 0,
      },
    },
  },
  from: 0,
  size: 20,
};
```

But then I get `doc_count: 0` for indices where there are matches because the index is not in the bool query.

How can I get the `doc_count` for all indices but not get search hits from unwanted indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your index constraint to [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html)

```
{
  index: 'all,indices,here',
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          query_string: {
            query: 'hello',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  aggs: {
    group_by_index: {
      terms: {
        field: '_index',
        min_doc_count: 0,
      },
    },
  },
  post_filter: {
    terms: {
      _index: 'only,search,hits,indices,here',
    },
  },
  from: 0,
  size: 20,
};
```